# Performance of the Equal operator Vs memcmp for primitive data types

Tags: c++, c, memcmp

I have been using memcmp function for compare 2 integers in my performance critical application. I had to use this other than using equal operators as I have to deal with the other datatypes generically. However, I suspected the memcpy performance for primitive data types and changed that to equal operator. However, the performance of the increased.

I just did some simple test as follows.

Using memcmp

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int iValue1 = atoi(argv[1]);
        int iValue2 = atoi(argv[2]);

        struct timeval start;
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)
        {
//              if (iValue1 == iValue2)
                if (memcmp(&iValue1, &iValue2, sizeof(int)) == 0)
                {
                        cout << "Hello" << endl;
                };
        };

        struct timeval end;
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

        cout << "Time taken : " << ((end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec)) << " us" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The output of the program was follows.

```
sujith@linux-1xs7:~> g++ -m64 -O3 Main.cpp
sujith@linux-1xs7:~> ./a.out 3424 234
Time taken : 13539618 us
sujith@linux-1xs7:~> ./a.out 3424 234
Time taken : 13534932 us
sujith@linux-1xs7:~> ./a.out 3424 234
Time taken : 13599818 us
sujith@linux-1xs7:~> ./a.out 3424 234
Time taken : 13639394 us
```

Using equal operator

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int iValue1 = atoi(argv[1]);
        int iValue2 = atoi(argv[2]);

        struct timeval start;
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)
        {
                if (iValue1 == iValue2)
//              if (memcmp(&iValue1, &iValue2, sizeof(int)) == 0)
                {
                        cout << "Hello" << endl;
                };
        };

        struct timeval end;
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

        cout << "Time taken : " << ((end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec)) << " us" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The output of the program was follows.

```
sujith@linux-1xs7:~> g++ -m64 -O3 Main.cpp
sujith@linux-1xs7:~> ./a.out 234 23423
Time taken : 9 us
sujith@linux-1xs7:~> ./a.out 234 23423
Time taken : 13 us
sujith@linux-1xs7:~> ./a.out 234 23423
Time taken : 14 us
sujith@linux-1xs7:~> ./a.out 234 23423
Time taken : 15 us
sujith@linux-1xs7:~> ./a.out 234 23423
Time taken : 16 us
```

Can someone please let me know whether the equal operator works faster than the memcmp for primitive data types? If so, What is happening there? Doesn't the equal operator use memcmp inside?

Comment: There is a very time-consuming if the environment by the memory access in bytes.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What do you mean? Are you saying that my tests are not identical and output may be very time to time?

Comment: Because it is optimized for access in the processing of the CPU size In general, the extra time it takes to access one byte at a time. memcmp is let's not apply the == as it is so that the comparison for each byte, instead of testing for a match with the specified size.

Comment: `Doesn't the equal operator use memcmp inside?` Very unlikely. Write a simple program comparing two ints and look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: I strongly suspect that, in the second case, the optimizer hoisted the check out of the loop, rewriting the program as `if (iValue1 == iValue2) { for (...) { cout ...; }  }`. So you are comparing millions of `memcpy` calls with just one comparison. Hence the dramatic difference in timing.

Comment: *I have been using memcmp function for compare 2 integers in my performance critical application.* Premature optimization?

Comment: *I had to use this other than using equal operators as I have to deal with the other datatypes generically.* You are using C++. Ever heard of operator overloading?

Comment: Why would a sane compiler make == slower than memcmp for a basic datatype?

Comment: @NeilKirk In fact, compilers have latitude to inline C standard library functions, and to optimise using assumptions not apparent from the function declaration.

Comment: @marko I don't see how that is relevant to my comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microbenchmarks are hard to write.

The loop in the first case compiles to (at `g++ -O3`):

```
    movl    $2000000000, %ebx
    jmp .L3
.L2:
    subl    $1, %ebx
    je  .L7
.L3:
    leaq    12(%rsp), %rsi
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
    movl    $4, %edx
    call    memcmp
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jne .L2
    ; code to do the printing omitted
    subl    $1, %ebx
    jne .L3
.L7:
    addq    $16, %rsp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    ret
```

The loop in the second case compiles to

```
    cmpl    %eax, %ebp
    je  .L7
.L2:
    addq    $8, %rsp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    ret
.L7:
    movl    $2000000000, %ebx
.L3:
    ; code to do the printing omitted
    subl    $1, %ebx
    jne .L3
    jmp .L2
```

Note that in the first case `memcmp` is called 2000000000 times. In the second case, the optimizer hoisted the comparison out of the loop, so it is done only once. Moreover, in the second case the compiler placed the two variables entirely in registers, while in the first one they need to be placed on the stack because you are taking their address.

Even when just looking at the comparison, compare two `int`s takes a single `cmpl` instruction. Using `memcmp` incurs a function call, and internally `memcmp` is likely to require some extra checks.

In this particular case, `clang++ -O3` compiles the `memcmp` to a single `cmpl` instruction. However, it doesn't hoist the check outside the loop if you use `memcmp`.

Comment: Thanks T.C for the answer and the advice on "Operator Overloading". :)

Comment: There is a possibility that `memcmp` compares byte by byte, thus 4 * (byte fetch, byte compare, loop overhead).  As T.C. stated, `operator==` can be compiled to using the processor's compare instruction.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews An optimized implementation would probably compare byte by byte until the alignment is right, and then compare many bytes at a time.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, more overhead. Even a simple check for alignment is more instructions than `operator==`.